# download file from s3 as csv by means of javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

I really think this is trivial one, but I just can't find the right answer.

I have a csv file on s3 bucket. I have link to it, which looks something like:
https://blabla-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/imaginefolder/testfilename.csv?AWSAccessKeyId=111&Expires=222&Signature=333

Now I want to put a link to it. When user clicks, csv file download should start in his browser.

I tried the following:

```
<a download href="https://blabla-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/imaginefolder/testfilename.csv?AWSAccessKeyId=111&Expires=222&Signature=333">Download</a>
```

And it works, but downloaded file is with txt extension.
I am not sure if the reason is in Amazon API configuration or in the way I am handling this ahref.

I saw that people recommend to use AWSJavaScriptSDK, But I am really interested to know if there is a way to do it by simple means.

Comment: What is the `Content-Type` of the file on S3 (see the metadata area in the console)?